# Deduce template parameter from member variable in constructor

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have a C++ library which is a wrapper for a C library. A factory class `Creator` creates objects of which each represents parts of the functionality of the C library.
These class constructors are private to ensure that all objects are created through that `Creator` class because the C library requires some internal magic (which I omitted in the following, simplified example).

It all works, but I have the following "problem":

In class `UsesAandB` I have to specify the template parameter of `A<>` twice:
Once in the member declaration (`std::shared_ptr<A<int>>`) and once in the initialization list of the constructor (`creator->createA<int>`).

Since I already know that member `aInt` will be of type `std::shared_ptr<A<int>>`, how can I use this knowledge to call the corresponding `createA<int>()` method in the constructor without repeating `int` or how can I avoid the call to `createA<int>()` at all?

```
#include <memory>

class Creator;

template<typename T>
class A
{
    friend class Creator;
private:
    A(int param) {}
    T value;
};

class B
{
    friend class Creator;
private:
    B(){}
};

class Creator
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    std::shared_ptr<A<T>> createA(int param) { return std::shared_ptr<A<T>>(new A<T>(param)); }
    std::shared_ptr<B> createB() { return std::shared_ptr<B>(new B());}
};

class UsesAandB
{
public:
    UsesAandB(std::shared_ptr<Creator> creator)
        : creator(creator),
          aInt(creator->createA<int>(0)),
          aDouble(creator->createA<double>(1)),
          b(creator->createB())
   {

   }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Creator> creator;
    std::shared_ptr<A<int>> aInt;
    std::shared_ptr<A<double>> aDouble;
    std::shared_ptr<B> b;
};

int main()
{
    auto creator = std::make_shared<Creator>();
    UsesAandB u(creator);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Class A could have a typedef (A::type for example) for the type it was instantiated with. You could then use that typedef. Edit: I am not sure that is possible to get out of the uninitialized shared pointer though. :)

Comment: @rozina: and use it like this? `aInt(creator->createA<A::type>(0))` ? ok, would work, but could `Creator` infer it somehow using this `typedef`?

Comment: Not like that, since A is a template so A::type would not work. A<int>::type would, but that achieves nothing though :) I will write an answer with an idea I have. Though I doubt you will be satisfied :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the type from the `shared_ptr`, you need to pass it to a template function like this one:

```
template <typename U>
shared_ptr< A<U> > CreateA( std::shared_ptr<Creator>& c,
                            const shared_ptr< A<U> >& p,
                            const U& val )
{
    return c->createA<U>(val);
}
```

Then simply:

```
aInt(CreateA(creator, aInt, 0 )),
```

Sample here - http://ideone.com/Np7f8t

Comment: I'd suggest passing the shared_ptr c by const reference, since the shared_ptr itself isn't modified (it can still call non-const functions of Creator).
Also, I don't understand why your function doesn't simply modify p instead of returning what p should be constructed with.

Comment: @KABoissonneault it could be a const reference (and the same applies for the `val` parameter), I didn't include it because the focus was on the method for extracting the type information. I didn't modify `p` because the function is used before the constructor body - it has to return a pointer and if it also modifies `p` it would be one function that does two things - not a good practice. So the `p` is just a type information parameter for me.

Answer (score 1):

My idea, don't know if it solves anything, but you do eliminate the chance of having different types in the declaration and constructor call.

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
    friend class Creator;
private:
    typedef T type;
    A(int param) {}
    T value;
};

class UsesAandB
{
typedef std::shared_ptr<A<int>> sharedA;

public:
    UsesAandB(std::shared_ptr<Creator> creator)
        : creator(creator),
          aInt(creator->createA<sharedA::element_type::type>(0)),
          aDouble(creator->createA<double>(1)),
          b(creator->createB())
   {

   }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<Creator> creator;
    sharedA aInt;
    std::shared_ptr<A<double>> aDouble;
    std::shared_ptr<B> b;
};
```

Comment: so I would have to `typedef`all use cases. still, how could `Creator` use the `typedef ... type` ?

Comment: @m.s. I must say that is beyond my knowledge. If `typdef` could be templated then I you could make a `typedef` for `std::shared_ptr<A<T>> `in `Creator`. Ofc you can make `Creator` a template class and then it would work.

Comment: @m.s. Although I am not sure why do you wan't `Creator` to use the `typedef ... type`? Your question states that you want to use the knowledge in  `UsesAandB` not in `Creator`.

Comment: ideally I would only have to specify the type once (when declaring the member variable) and from there one ` UsesAandB` passes the type automatically to `Creator` without having to care about it again

Answer (score 1):

You could add the following static template function

```
template <class T>
static std::shared_ptr<T> create1(std::shared_ptr<Creator> &creator, std::shared_ptr<T> &,T value)
{
   return creator->createA(value) ;
}
```

An then initialize like this:

```
UsesAandB(std::shared_ptr<Creator> creator)
        : creator(creator),
          aInt(create1((creator, aInt, 0)),
          aDouble(create1(creator, aDouble, 1)),
          b(creator->createB())
   {

   }
```

create1 requires the shared pointer only to deduce the right type.
A problem is that this code should raise a warning (this used in nitializer list)

Comment: ops, I forgot to insert the call.