# Deduce the template type of a member shared_ptr

Tags: c++, templates, shared-ptr, auto

So, after much pondering, this ([Deduce template parameter from member variable in constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30707958/deduce-template-parameter-from-member-variable-in-constructor)) is not the question I was going to ask, so here goes. Let's make it a little more simple. Suppose I have a situation like

```
shared_ptr<SomeType> myPtr;
// ...
myPtr = make_shared<SomeType>();
```

question: would there be a way to figure out `SomeType` based on the type of `myPtr`, either at compile or run time? I appreciate in this case I could have just done

```
auto myPtr = make_shared<SomeType>();
```

and saved myself a few keystrokes, but consider the following:

```
class MyClass {
    shared_ptr<SomeType> _memberName;
public:
    void setup();
};
```

where `setup()` is called after the instance is constructed, and creates that pointer. In this case, I can't declare a member as `auto` (without making it static, it would seem). So, again: is there a way to avoid all those redundant and error-prone keystrokes?

Comment: `decltype(myPtr)::element_type`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
_memberName = std::make_shared<decltype(_memberName)::element_type>();
```

but it is doesn't save typing against

```
_memberName = std::make_shared<SomeType>();
```

and it also seems less readable.

And for both, error-prone keystrokes is pointed by compiler :-)

Comment: Yeah, if this is the only way, might as well be redundant :)

Answer (score -2):

If it is for MyClass, could you do:

```
template<typename T> {
class MyClass {
    shared_ptr<T> _memberName;
public:
    void setup();
};
```

Comment: I could, but this isn't the case.